# ng-deep being ignored when reloading page?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have utilized Angular Material 5 and used ng-deep to customize my mat-inputs, and they work fine when I first load my page.

However, when I switch to a different page and then go back to the page with my mat-inputs, it either applies the ng-deep css AGAIN (for example it will add padding twice), or it will just completely ignore the ng-deep css.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I should even approach fixing this. None of my other ng-deep css behaves this way. This problem only occurs on this one page, and it only occurs in Safari and Edge browsers. Chrome is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `ng-deep` (and other aliases) are currently deprecated and it's support is being removed from major browsers and angular.

See: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Here you can find more information about applying custom styles to Angular Material components: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

for ex. make use of higher specificity:

```
.myapp-no-padding-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  padding: 0;
}
```